# Was "The Black Echo"'s diegetic existence merely a nod to the books or an element from the books?

Tags: book-adaptation, bosch

When [*Bosch*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3502248/) spends the night with Brasher in his hill house overviewing L.A. and she notes that it is quite a view for a detective, he says that *"Paramount payed that view"*. He tells her that the movie "The Black Echo" was loosely based on one of his cases and his apartment was basically bought from the royalties for his story.

Now in reality [*The Black Echo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Echo) is in fact one of Michael Connelly's novels, the first one in the *Harry Bosch* series this TV-show is based on. I wonder though, if this diegetic existence of "The Black Echo" was just a little nod from the TV-show to the novels or **if the novels already featured *The Black Echo*'s story as having been turned into a book or movie inside the novels' universe** and referenced in a later work (one that the TV-show is in turn adapted from).

Comment: In the books the house was paid for with royalties from a TV show about Bosch and his former partner; perhaps they thought that would be *too* meta! I don't know if any later book refers to earlier cases being novelised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the books there are multiple references across several books to the fact that a prior case of his had been turned into a TV mini-series and he had worked on the show as a technical adviser along with his then-partner.

This case occurs prior to the chronological start of the book series and hasn't been covered in them to my knowledge. It's definitely not *The Black Echo* case as the TV-deal has already happened and is mentioned in the book. The money from that work and the royalties provided the capital for him to buy his house (his partner used the money to retire).

At least up to the end of book 11 "The Closers" the title of this series hasn't been mentioned, and it's likely that the use of the "Black Echo" title is a nod to fans of the books. Given that each season of the show adapts elements from multiple novels into the season it was probably a safe bet that the show wouldn't do a straight adaptation of the book *The Black Echo* (elements of the book were used in formulating season 3) so it was unlikely to get too confusing in that regard and the change to a movie in the TV series is probably to avoid going to meta as this would risk straying from "respectful nod" into "tongue in cheek" territory!

The only scene I can remember discussing it directly is the one the OP refers to where he talks about it with Brasher when she visits his house in season one but I'd have to re-watch to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the series, Bosch has a conversation in which he gives more detail about the story being turned into a movie.  Books mention it first.

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?